Bounded functions and relationship to its Fourier components
I apologize in advance if the question isn't stated in a proper math language.
Let $f(\theta)$ be a real function, where $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ is an angle with the following properties:

$f(\theta = 0) = 1$
$f(-\theta) = f(\theta)$
$|f(\theta)| \le 1 $ for all $\theta$

Now I defined the Fourier transformation as
$$f_l = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{2\pi} e^{-il\theta} f(\theta)$$
My question is, can we show that $f_l \ge 0$?
I can show that the previous three conditions lead to

$\sum_l f_l = 1$
$f^*_l = f_l = f_{-l}$
$\sum_l f_l^2 \le 1$ which is a necessary but not sufficient.

These three constraints don't imply that $f_l \ge 0$. However, for the life of me I cannot find an example of $f(\theta)$ that has a negative $f_l$.
Either an example of such $f(\theta)$ that has negative $f_l$ or a proof that it cannot exist will answer my question.

Note that $f_0$ represents the average value. It is straightforward to see that a function that satisfies the conditions but has negative average can be constructed.

For example, $f(\theta) = \max(-1, |1-{4 \over \pi} t|)$ has $f_0 = -{1 \over 2}$.

@copper.hat thanks a lot! this is very helpful. Would you have any thoughts if we can say anything useful about the other components $f_{l\neq0}$?

I did find an example that would give negative $f_l$ even for $l\neq0$, so there are no such restriction.
$$f(\theta) = \left(2e^{-\alpha\sin^2(\theta/2)} - 1\right)^2$$
It is easy to check that it satisfies the three conditions in the question. An explicit FFT on this function shows that we can have $f_{l=1} < 0$ for non-zero values of $\alpha$. One can also write $f_l$ explicitly in terms of the modified Bessel functions.

